# swift when api response model data comes nil, app crashes even after using if let statement

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wqep.png)    if let tracking_id = activeridedata.tracking_id {
cell.lblTrackingId.text = tracking_id
}

compiler gives fatal error while cell is loading and its due to nil data in model classes. Even after using if let statement, app crashes when nil data appears.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If activeridedata may not exist, declare it as an optional type and use it as follows.

```
if let tracking_id = activeridedata?.tracking_id { cell.lblTrackingId.text = tracking_id }
```